# Sending, but not able to receive UDP messages with C# app

Tags: .net, udp, udpclient

I am trying to write a small application that would communicate with another program by using
the UDP protocol.

I need to be able to both send as well as receive messages over UDP. I am able to send messages,
and these seem to be working fine. However no data gets received. I can see with wireshark that the
response messages are being sent by the server.

Here is the code

```
`using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DeviceLinkApp
{
    class Program
    {
        private const int DLPort = 1711;
        private static UdpClient receivingUdpClient;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BackgroundWorker senderWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
            senderWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(SenderThread);
            senderWorker.RunWorkerAsync();

            //Creates a UdpClient for reading incoming data.
            receivingUdpClient = new UdpClient(DLPort);

            try
            {
                receivingUdpClient.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(recv), null);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        //CallBack
        private static void recv(IAsyncResult res)
        {
            IPEndPoint RemoteIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 1711);
            byte[] received = receivingUdpClient.EndReceive(res, ref RemoteIpEndPoint);

            //Process codes

            Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(received));
            receivingUdpClient.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(recv), null);
        }

        private static void SenderThread(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs args )
        {
            UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient();

            while (true)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);

                Byte[] sendBytes1 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("R/115");
                Byte[] sendBytes2 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("R/103");
                Byte[] sendBytes3 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("R/40");
                try
                {
                    udpClient.Send(sendBytes1, sendBytes1.Length, "192.168.1.164", DLPort);
                    udpClient.Send(sendBytes2, sendBytes2.Length, "192.168.1.164", DLPort);
                    udpClient.Send(sendBytes3, sendBytes3.Length, "192.168.1.164", DLPort);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}`
```

I am a bit confused here as to how exactly set up the listener here. The server is setup to receive
data on port 1711 and this works OK. However it sends a response not to port 1711 obviously, but to the port that my client uses. This port seems to be different every time.

Tried some experimenting and setting the listener client to the same port number as the sending client gave me an exception.

Just to clarify, I think it works something like this : (And wireshark seems to confirm).
Client (mine) sends from port <sth like 55567> to Server on port 1711.
Server (remote) sends from port 1711 to port 55567.

Sooo... I am guessing I should be listening to port 55567??? and not 1711?! Maybe I am not making a lot of sense here, thus far I have tried to use really basic example code, but I am never
seeing any responses from the server, even though I know that these are getting sent.

Should I use different client objects for sending and receiving? UDP really is a new topic
for me, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I will try this approach as well. Last night I did finally manage to get communication to work. Looks like the key was to add a timeout for the Receiving cycle. The problem is that if the read fails then code execution gets blocked. In my case it seems that the server does not respond every time, or the first answers might get lost (not sure what the exact issue is yet).

In any case I did get this code to communicate with the server:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DeviceLinkApp
{
    class Program
    {
        private const int DLPort = 1711;
        private static string myIp;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Get the Name of HOST  
            string hostName = Dns.GetHostName();
            Console.WriteLine(hostName);

            // Get the IP from GetHostByName method of dns class.
            myIp = Dns.GetHostByName(hostName).AddressList[0].ToString();
            Console.WriteLine("IP Address is : " + myIp);


            BackgroundWorker senderWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
            senderWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(SenderThread);
            senderWorker.RunWorkerAsync();

            Console.ReadLine();

            /* TODO : Clean up connections etc.... */
        }

        private static void SenderThread(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs args )
        {
            UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient();
            IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 1711);

            udpClient.Client.ReceiveTimeout = 1000;

            while (true)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);

                Byte[] sendBytes1 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("R/115");
                Byte[] sendBytes2 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("R/103");
                Byte[] sendBytes3 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("R/40");
                try
                {
                    //udpClient.Send(sendBytes1, sendBytes1.Length, "192.168.1.164", DLPort);
                    //udpClient.Send(sendBytes2, sendBytes2.Length, "192.168.1.164", DLPort);
                    //udpClient.Send(sendBytes3, sendBytes3.Length, "192.168.1.164", DLPort);

                    //udpClient.Send(sendBytes1, sendBytes1.Length, myIp, DLPort);
                    //udpClient.Send(sendBytes2, sendBytes2.Length, myIp, DLPort);
                    udpClient.Send(sendBytes3, sendBytes3.Length, myIp, DLPort);


                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Tx failed");
                    //Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                }

                try
                {
                    byte[] received = udpClient.Receive(ref remoteEndPoint);
                    Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(received));
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Rx failed");
                    //Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```